# Integration by parts Gaussian measure

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, gaussian-integral

I'm trying to prove an integration by parts formula for the standard Gaussian measure $\gamma:=\frac{e^{-\frac{x^{2}}2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}dx$ on $\mathbb{R}$. The formula is as follows:

$\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)g'(x)\gamma(dx)=-\int_{\mathbb{R}}(f'(x)-xf(x))g(x)\gamma(dx)$.

I do not see where to start with this. It may be too advanced for me but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Plug in the formula for the density of $\gamma$ and use the usual integration by parts formula (for the Lebesgue measures).

Comment: That's very helpful thank you. I took $h(x):=f(x)\frac{e^{-\frac{x^{2}}2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$ and then applied integration by parts using $h(x)$ and $g'(x)$. However, I found that I am left with an extra term $[g(x)f(x)\frac{e^{-\frac{x^{2}}2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}]_{\mathbb{R}}$ along with the desired result. I cannot see why this would be equal to $0$, so I'm not sure where I have gone wrong.

Comment: To prove anything you need _hypotheses_. Here for example the "extra term" is $\lim_{A\to\infty}(F(A)-F(-A))$, and you need an appropriate hypothesis to ensure that limit is $0$.

Comment: Ok, I understand now. The way this question was posed did not give any additional conditions for f and g. I suppose part of my answer should be describing the conditions under which this formula can be applied.